# Fedora 25 NetBios/wins issues

Tags: fedora, samba, winbind, netbios

I am trying to set up local hostname resolution on my Fedora machine.
I have installed `samba-winbind samba-winbind-clients pam_krb5` and then went through the procedure shown on: https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Fedora_25&p=samba&f=3

I have added wins to my `/etc/nsswitch.conf` as follows:
`hosts:      files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname wins`

I then try to use wins to find my raspberry-pi which I can find on my Ubuntu install.

If I add wins before myhostname I get:

`$ ping my-pi
Segmentation fault`

When it is as shown above I get:

`$ ping my-pi
ping: my-pi: System error`

Any pointers on how to diagnose/solve this issue would be much appreciated.